# Is there a way to get a blob specific version based on the branch TAG?

Tags: git, powershell, azure-devops-rest-api

I need to generate a .zip with the compiled version of a wpf .Net project. But I need it compilation only contains the compiled objects that have been changed, and not all the files.

I am using a PowerShell Task in a Azure DevOps CD Pipeline. Then I use Azure DevOps Rest API to get the last version of a file in a specific TAG of a branch.

Comment: A tag is just a name for a commit (or other internal Git object). Translate the tag to a hash ID and use that to fish out the Git object. Whether that's allowed, or possible at all, via the Azure REST API I have no idea, but you've tagged this `git`.

Comment: So you want to specify the branch, tag, and file and download the file using the Azure DevOps Rest API?  Is that correct?

Comment: Yes It's that correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use the [Git Items API.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)

**Example:**

For a file in the repo with this tag:

[image]

You would make the API call like:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repo}/items?path=temp.txt&versionDescriptor.versionType=tag&versionDescriptor.version=v1.0.0&download=true
```

Comment: Thanks Matt.. It is what I needed.